# Update tag after delete of row in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

Okay, so my issue is that I'm deleting rows in a tableview upon a click on a button, and I'm identifying the row to delete by getting the sender's tag and removing it from my data source array and deleting the row from the table...

In cellForRowAtIndexPath (relevant part is deleteBtn): ***BELOW IS THE FIXED AND WORKING CODE**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"questionCell";

    HTQuestionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[HTQuestionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    dict = _questionsArray[indexPath.row];

    NSMutableAttributedString *atbString;
    NSMutableAttributedString *atbQuestionString;

    atbString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"person"] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:34]}];

    atbQuestionString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"question"] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:34]}];

    [atbString appendAttributedString:atbQuestionString];

    [cell.questionTxtView setAttributedText:atbString];

    [cell.deleteBtn setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.showBtn setTag:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"Delete Button : %@", cell.deleteBtn);

    [cell.deleteBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteMsg:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.showBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(showMsg:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
```

And in the delete method I then do this:

```
UIButton *tempButton = sender;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tempButton.tag inSection:0];
[_questionsArray removeObjectAtIndex:tempButton.tag];
[_dataTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[_dataTable reloadData];
```

I've also tried with beginUpdates and endUpdates instead of reloadData, but none have any effect...

So, when I'm testing it, I have two rows... Initially their tag's get set correctly - 0 and 1... But when I then delete row 0, and check the tag for the new first row, it still has the tag = 1, when it now should be 0... It's almost like it doesn't update the button's tag after the deletion...

Comment: Cellforrowatindexpath is not being called after the delete. Because you don't have any need to reload the cells. You need to reload the table if you want that method to be called.

Comment: @Bergasms Already had reloadData after the 4 lines in the delete method though :( Let me just update the original question, so you can see where it is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution 1: use:

```
[_dataTable reloadData];
```

to reset the tags, as cellForRowAtIndexPath is called again

Solution 2: use:

```
[_dataTable beginUpdates];
[_dataTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[_dataTable endUpdates];
```

which will also call cellForRowAtIndexPath and update the tags

Comment: Updated my question, since I already had reloadData, and I've tried with beginUpdates and endUpdates now as well...

Comment: you'll have to show us your complete cellForRowAtIndexPath ... are you setting the tag inside the if(cell=nil) block ?

Comment: Your cellForRowAtIndexPath has many problems. Firstly you should be using customTableViewCells with deleteButton, showBtn etc. as properties and use cell.delBtn etc. instead of [cell viewWithTag: 33], which is very wrong. Now coming to your issue, could you put a NSLog(@"Delete Button : %@", deleteBtn) below UIButton *deleteBtn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag: 34]; line ... and then delete one row.. I think deletebutton will be logged as NULL after you delete a row. Because 2nd time, your deleteButton tag will no longer be 34, rather its been changed to your indexPath.row value. Makes sense?

Comment: Okay... Got it to work :) Created a UITableViewCell class, added the properties with IBOutlets, and changed my cellForRowAtIndexPath accordingly, and it worked... Thanks!

Comment: I have a delete button on cell and a text field. creating index path from tag deleting wrong cell if I delete cell in between the cells collection. on the other hand if I reloading the table its resetting the values of my changed text fields. :-(