# Use beginUpdates/endUpdates for deleting row from tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Deleting a row from tableview using `beginupdates`/`endupdates` instead of `reloadData`.

```
 viewTeachertblView.beginUpdates()
 let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
 self.viewTeachertblView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
 viewTeachertblView.endUpdates()
```

This method doesnot work as `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called and `indexpath` gets out of track while deleting.

Here is the full source code:

```
extension ViewController :UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return teacherObj.count
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("teacherCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TeacherTblVIewCell
        print(teacherObj[indexPath.row].valueForKey("teacher_name") as? String)
        cell.teacherName?.text = teacherObj[indexPath.row].valueForKey("teacher_name") as? String
        cell.deleteBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.deleteBtn.addTarget(self, action: "deleteThisTeacher:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        return cell

    }


    func deleteThisTeacher(sender:UIButton){

        print("delete this username")
        //first delete this user name from the coredata
        print(sender.tag)
        teacherObj.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)
       // self.viewTeachertblView.reloadData()
        viewTeachertblView.beginUpdates()
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
        self.viewTeachertblView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
        viewTeachertblView.endUpdates()


    }

}
```

How to delete tableview row the `beginupates`/`endupdates` instead of deleting object from the `datasource` and reloading `tableview`

Comment: Setting the button's tag based on the cell's `indexPath` is not the proper solution in a table view with dynamic rows. There are far better ways to determine the row for the button when the button is tapped.

Comment: please can you suggest a bettter one?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27107160/1226963 for the proper solution.

Comment: thanks for the answer..but why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679930/update-tag-after-delete-of-row-in-tableview  says cellForRowAtIndexPath is called with beginupdates/endupdates and mine doesnot

Comment: Create a delegate method in the cell class and call that once the button is pressed and you'll get which cell was pressed and therefore the indexpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rmaddy told this does the job

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("teacherCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TeacherTblVIewCell
        print(teacherObj[indexPath.row].valueForKey("teacher_name") as? String)
        cell.teacherName?.text = teacherObj[indexPath.row].valueForKey("teacher_name") as? String
        cell.deleteBtn.addTarget(self, action: "deleteThisTeacher:event:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        return cell

    }

    func deleteThisTeacher(sender:UIButton, event: UIEvent){

        print("delete this username")
        //first delete this user name from the coredata
        print(sender.tag)

        if let touch = event.touchesForView(sender)?.first  {
            let point = touch.locationInView(viewTeachertblView)
            if let indexPath = viewTeachertblView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point) {

                print(indexPath.row)
                 teacherObj.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                 self.viewTeachertblView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    func deleteThisTeacher(sender:UIButton){
         let point = viewTeachertblView.convertPoint(CGPointZero, fromView: sender)
         if let indexPath = viewTeachertblView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point) {
            teacherObj.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            viewTeachertblView.beginUpdates()
            self.viewTeachertblView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
            viewTeachertblView.endUpdates()
         }
    }
```

Comment: whats the beneit of wrapping that delete code at beginUpdates() and endupdates?

Comment: so that specific animations can be done to the row .Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/beginUpdates  and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/endUpdates for details.

Comment: deleteRowsAtIndexPaths it does the job..no need that block for the animation

Comment: When this method is called in an animation block defined by the beginUpdates and endUpdates methods, UITableView defers any insertions of rows or sections until after it has handled the deletions of rows or sections. Thats why you need beginUpdates and endUpdates

Comment: if let touch = event.touchesForView(sender)?.first  {
            let point = touch.locationInView(viewTeachertblView)
            if let indexPath = viewTeachertblView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point) {
             
                print(indexPath.row)
                 teacherObj.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                 self.viewTeachertblView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
            }
        }
just this does the job....and really was that worth?